# Non-caps spelling of acronyms

Tags: spelling

I noticed that in Italian acronyms usually aren't fully capitalized, e.g. "Usa" instead of "USA". I haven't seen this spelling convention in any other language and am curious if there's an explanation for it.

Comment: I'm also really curious about this.

Comment: I don't agree that acronyms _usually_ aren't fully capitalized. It might be true that some newspapers write "Usa" instead of "USA", but I think I still see capitalized acronyms much more. Moreover, this doesn't seem to be an Italian-only thing. For example, both the [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a) and the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/en/articles/art20130702112133548) recommend the lower case after the first letter, when the acronym is pronounced as a word

Comment: The reason might be the same in Italy as well. Acronyms like "USA", "IVA" ("VAT") or "RAI" are pronounced as words in Italian, and not by spelling the individual letters

Answer (score 3):

The following extract from [l’Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/sigle) covers the whole issue on acronyms in Italian. It doesn’t explain how  the different usages developed, but it lists the  uses  that have become common according to context. Regarding the use of capital letters they say there is no fixed rule, but the use you mention, with only the first letter capitalized, is commonly found  in non-technical texts:

> Sulla grafia i punti di maggiore incertezza sono l'uso delle maiuscole (o minuscole) e l'inserimento del punto tra una lettera e l'altra. ***Per l'inserimento delle maiuscole non ci sono regole precise, anche se l'uso sembra aver fissato alcuni criteri:***
>
> - le sigle possono essere scritte con tutte maiuscole (tipo IBM, BMW, WWF ecc.) o possono avere soltanto la prima lettera maiuscola (tipo Spa, Eu, Ogm, ecc.); ***questo secondo caso sembra più frequente quando la sigla sia contenuta in un testo divulgativo, mentre nei testi tecnici è più frequente la forma con tutte maiuscole (EU, OGM)***.
> - Ci sono poi sigle che sono diventate lessemi a tutti gli effetti come laser, radar, sonar, ufo che si sottraggono, in quanto ormai nomi comuni, a qualsiasi uso della maiuscola iniziale. ***Gli acronimi che formano parole di senso compiuto richiedono invece tutte maiuscole*** poiché, essendo prevalentemente parole di senso compiuto, è necessaria una differenziazione grafica per non creare ambiguità con la parola comune corrispondente (es. Corsica/CORSICA, presto/PRESTO, Monica/MONICA, ecc.).
> - Per quel che riguarda l'uso del punto tra una lettera e l'altra, la tendenza è nettamente orientata verso l'abbandono di questa pratica. Un altro aspetto grafico che però è tangente alla morfologia è la segnalazione del plurale con la duplicazione delle lettere della sigla, tipo FFSS per Ferrovie dello Stato: si tratta di una convenzione che si sta perdendo e troviamo più frequentemente "le FS", "le Asl" anche se qualche residuo resta in alcune abbreviazioni, tipo sigg., proff., pp., segg.

Comment: Thanks! I found that in English the usage also varies, some style guides (esp. British) recommend initial caps for well-known pronounceable acronyms (Nato instead of NATO). In Italian I still find it confusing to read "Ue" but I'll get used to it.

Comment: Some acromyms seem to get written in lower case only: pm (pubblico ministero),  ddl (disegno di legge). Maybe because these are not proper nouns? For some reason, the general tendency in (non-technical) Italian seems to be to avoid capital letters (and dots) as much as possible.