# Come si esprime "riesgos laborales" in italiano?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Nel mio paese si parla di "riesgos laborales" (in castigliano, in catalano sarebbe "riscos laborals") per riferirsi a tutte le possibili situazioni che possano mettere a rischio la salute dei lavoratori oppure produrre o peggiorare un problema di salute nei lavoratori. Esiste una legge chiamata ["ley de prevención de riesgos laborales"](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1995-24292) ("prevención" significa "prevenzione") fatta per proteggere i lavoratori da tali rischi. Immagino che in Italia esista qualcosa di simile, però veramente non ne ho idea.

Ecco la mia domanda: come si esprime questo concetto in italiano? Ricercando "rischi" e "lavoro" con Google, mi appaiono parecchie espressioni: "rischi lavorativi", "rischi sul lavoro", "rischi sui luoghi di lavoro", "rischi per la salute sul lavoro",  "rischi per la sicurezza sul lavoro", "rischi per la salute dei lavoratori", ecc.

Comment: "sicurezza del/sul lavoro", con la differenza che sicurezza è contrapposto a rischio.

Comment: L'analoga legge italiana è questa: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testo_unico_sulla_sicurezza_sul_lavoro

Comment: Ah, OK, grazie @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Italia l'ente che si occupa della sicurezza sul lavoro e prevenzione dei rischi si chiama INAIL, acronimo di Istituto Nazionale per l'Assicurazione contro gli Infortuni sul Lavoro.

All'interno del sito, nella sezione [Prevenzione e sicurezza](https://www.inail.it/cs/internet/attivita/prevenzione-e-sicurezza.html) si può leggere:

> L’Inail svolge attività di prevenzione dei **rischi lavorativi**, di
>   informazione, di formazione e assistenza in materia di sicurezza e
>   salute sul lavoro.

Direi quindi che la migliore traduzione sia appunto rischi lavorativi, per analogia con la legge spagnola che regola gli adempimenti necessari.

Comment: Ah! Ottimo che si trovi l'espressione "prevenzione dei rischi lavorativi"!

Comment: E, una volta in più, appare una [sigla](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/9823/) con soltanto la prima lettera maiuscola e tutte le altre minuscole, cosa che a me è sempre sembrata tanto strana...